# Single line if statement in reduce statement not working

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, arrow-functions

I'm trying to write a *reduce* statement that given an array of strings, return the array index that contains the word 'lace'.

I got it to work with a multi-line if statement, but it doesn't work when I use a single-line if statement:

input array

```
arr = [ 'tasselled', 'black', 'low-top', 'lace-up' ]
```

expected output

```
[3] // since the string 'lace' is in the 3rd index of the array
```

My code

```
// works (multi-line if statement)
arr.reduce( function(a,e,i) {
    if (e.indexOf('lace') >= 0) {
      a.push(i)
    }
    return a
  }, [])

// returns [3]
```

```
// doesn't work (single-line if statement)
arr.reduce( (a,e,i) => e.indexOf('lace')>=0 ? a.push(i) : 0, []);

// side note - can you do single-line if-statements without the else statement? (without the ': 0')

// returns error:
TypeError: a.push is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason it's not working is because your ternary operation returns a number in both scenarios. [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the `length` of the array and not the array itself.

So you can change it to use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const arr = [ 'tasselled', 'black', 'low-top', 'lace-up' ]
const output = arr.reduce((a,e,i) => e.includes('lace') ? a.concat(i) : a, []);

console.log(output)
```

Another option is to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) of the array

```js
const arr = [ 'tasselled', 'black', 'low-top', 'lace-up' ]
const output = [...arr.keys()].filter(i => arr[i].includes('lace'))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I don't know that `a.concat(i)` works as `a.push(i)` but return array - nice +1

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski `concat` returns the new array but `push` returns the length

Comment: I'm surprised I missed that too. I concat a lot.. I should have caught that. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

In your reduce statement if indexOf <0 then you return 0 instead of array, try

```js
arr = [ 'tasselled', 'black', 'low-top', 'lace-up' ];

let r=arr.reduce( (a,e,i) => (e.indexOf('lace')>=0 ? a.push(i) : 0, a), []);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Got it. The placement of parentheses was important here. Not sure how obvious that would be to newcomers.

Comment: @RichS the parentheses is not important for implicit returns but here it is used for the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: Good clarification.